# How to use Table to create 3x3 Matrix in Mathematica

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica

I use the table function to create a 3x3 matrix in index notation. I assume that I can access the element in first row and first column using A[[1,1]] but instead I need to use A[[1,1,1]]. How can I define a 3x3 matrix so that I can access each element by using A[[rowNum,colNum]] notation? Please see code below:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
A = Table[Subscript[a, i, j], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}] // MatrixForm
A[[1, 1]]
A = {{Subscript[a, 1, 1], Subscript[a, 1, 2], 
    Subscript[a, 1, 3]}, {Subscript[a, 2, 1], Subscript[a, 2, 2], 
    Subscript[a, 2, 3]}, {Subscript[a, 3, 1], Subscript[a, 3, 2], 
    Subscript[a, 3, 3]}} // MatrixForm
A[[1, 1]]
```

Comment: `Table` creates your matrix, but you then apply `MatrixForm`, which wraps it.  Don't do that, and you'll be fine.

Comment: to make it look nice with `MatrixForm` use parenthesis like this:  `( A = Table[...] ) //MatrixForm `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `// MatrixForm` from your definitions of `A`, the reason being that `MatrixForm` like most of the `*Form` functions is essentially a formatting function. To compute things, keep all initial variables holding input data and intermediate variables computable, and only format at the end when you want to present results. As defined above, the outmost function head of your `A` is `MatrixForm`, so `A[[1]]` rather than `A` is the computable matrix value you probably intended.